# Flutter: How to change FutureBuilder connection.state

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here i am hitting an api to get the data but and i am getting the data as i have printed the data. But when i am using FutureBuilder connection.state it is returning none and returns the view. I want to know to the the state of connection.state to Done so that i can view my view.

```dart
class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardScreen createState() => _DashboardScreen();

}


class _DashboardScreen extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  Future<DashboardModel> futureDashboard;

  //   api hit

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        futureDashboard = dashboardData();
      }
      );
    });
  }


  // setting the data in the view created

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // scaffold view
    return new Scaffold(

      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,


        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        child: FutureBuilder<DashboardModel>(
            future: futureDashboard,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DashboardModel> futureDashboard) {
              switch (futureDashboard.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                              'No Connection Message')
                      )
                  );
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('Active result...');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Text('Awaiting result...');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  print(futureDashboard);

                  if (futureDashboard.hasData) {
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text("data"),);
                  } else if (futureDashboard.hasError) {
                    return showSimpleFlushbar(
                        context, "${futureDashboard.error}");
                  }
                  return Container(
                    child: Text('error'),
                  );
              }
              return Container(
                child: Text('errornot'),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please have a look at how to ask a question and edit your question to improve your chance of someone answering! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

first you gotta check that the state of your class is stateless or stateful ,from the code i see,its not clear and also when modifying the data you gotta use setstate function and modify the data in it for example:- setState(() { *myState = newValue; });
hope it helps ;) -*-